# posicionar la fecha al lado del icono en un input date con calendar picker indicator

Tags: html, css, calendar

tengo el siguiente input tipe date, he puesto colores, y demás, pero lo que necesito es que el texto (la fecha) se quede posicionada justo al lado del icono

[image: posicion]

si muevo con margenes o posiciones se desplaza todo, la fecha + icono, y si la columna div está muy ensanchada se separan demasiado... y necesito que esté la fecha posicionada justo al lado del icono.

gracias.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: Hola :) Podrías añadir el código HTML y css a la pregunta? Así podría ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, al final lo solucioné poniendo en el html (tambien valido para añadir al css) el estilo float:right